# How to access an element in an array when only its number of rows is known?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm solving a system of differential equations in pythons to find `Z`.

```
sol = solve_ivp(conv, tspan, Z0,method='BDF')
aa=sol.t
bb=sol.y
```

then I'm finding `X` as

```
X=v1.dot(bb) where `v1`is a transformation matrix.
```

I need to find the value of second row of `X`at every integration step to execute the program as

```
X[:,0]=[0,0,0,0]
def conv(t,Z):
   if  (second element of 4*1 X )> .7
   Zdot=A*Z+B*U
sol = solve_ivp(conv, tspan, Z0,method='BDF')
aa=sol.t
bb=sol.y
X=v1.dot(bb)
```

I want the if condition to be checked at every step and then the 
`Zdot=A*Z+B*U`to be executed.
I just know the no. of rows of X at every integration step so can't use a for loop.
how do i do it?

Comment: Do you want ALL values in the 2nd row of X to meet the if statement condition or one element in 2nd row is enough? What is the shape of `X`?

Comment: All elements.Shape of X is [4,n],where n can be determined only after solving the equations fully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it like this using `np.all` to check all elements:

```
def conv(t,Z):
   if np.all(X[1, :]> .7):
       Zdot=A*Z+B*U
```

Comment: for the shape of X suppose [4,100], would  `np.all(X[1, :])` check the array at every step and then return `Zdot`?

Comment: @hinataexc what do you mean by "every step"? How do you define a step?

Comment: eg, for X of size 4*100, I want to access the second element of every column from 1 to 100.

Comment: @hinataexc Yes, `np.all(X[1, :]> .7)` checks ALL elements in 2nd row (a.k.a. 2nd element of every column) to be greater than 0.7. There was also a little typo I fixed. Please use the edited code.

Comment: I'm still not able to get the correct results. I'll post the link for my whole code here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421706/incorrect-results-obtained-while-using-np-all-while-using-solve-ivp-in-python

Comment: your code is a bit confusing. Here you said you want to check all elements of 2nd row of X. In your new post, X has single element in rows. And you have used X[1] instead of X[1,:] which makes it wrong because now your are comparing X[1] which is an array to a number. Maybe you can elaborate on what exactly X looks like in different steps? Does it change its shape by adding columns?